# Php foreach delete mysql and images from folder

Tags: php, mysql

Hey im having an issue on deleting mysql data and also deleting images on folder at the **same time**.

Im okey with deleting mysql image link from database but i couldnt manage to delete images from ftp folder at the same time. What im doing wrong if you can help me you can save my 3th day ^^

***I have changed codes recently seems like all correct but it doesnt remove the images from ftp ?***

**gallery.php**

```
<form  action="../function.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="urun_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['urun_id']; ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="urunfoto_resimyol[]" value="<?php echo $urunfotocek['urunfoto_resimyol']; ?> ">

    <div align="right" class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" name="urunfotosil"  class="btn btn-danger "><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete Selected</button>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="urun-foto-yukle.php?urun_id=<?php echo $_GET['urun_id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload Images</a>
...
```

**function.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['urunfotosil'])) {
    $urun_id=$_POST['urun_id'];
    echo $checklist = $_POST['urunfotosec'];
    foreach($checklist as $list) {
        $sil=$db->prepare("DELETE from urunfoto where urunfoto_id=:urunfoto_id");
        $kontrol=$sil->execute(array(
                                   'urunfoto_id' => $list
                                   ));
    }
    if ($kontrol) {
        $resimsilunlink=$_POST['urunfoto_resimyol'];
        foreach ($resimsilunlink as $resimyol) {
            unlink("../../$resimyol");
        }

        Header("Location:../production/urun-galeri.php?urun_id=$urun_id&durum=ok");
    } else {
        Header("Location:../production/urun-galeri.php?urun_id=$urun_id&durum=no");
    }
}
```

Comment: The part `$resimsilunlink=$list['urunfoto_resimyol'];` is placed outside the `foreach` loop, so `unlink()` is executed only once.

Comment: So how can i fix it ? im not good at english and im still learning php. Just trying to fix this since 3 days i have checked like 100 solution but non of them seems working.

Comment: its actually deleting mysql from database but not in ftp

Comment: FYI you don't need to call `prepare()` each time through the loop. Call it once before the loop, then execute it with different parameters each time.

Comment: What is `$list['urunfoto_resimyol']`? Is that really the correct variable? `$list` is the variable you were using for iteration in `foreach`, so after the loop it contains the last ID in `$checklist`, not an associative array.

Comment: Maybe you meant `$_POST['urunfoto_resimyol']`?

Comment: nope "echo $checklist = $_POST['urunfotosec'];" this is for multiupload images on another php file. its selector "urunfotosec" means "selectphotos" in english.

Comment: @AlperAslan Save the path you want to delete in a variable. What is the return value of `file_exists($variable)` for the path you try to delete? What is the return value of `unlink($variable)` when you try to delete it? Please edit your question to include the output you get.

Comment: $resimsilunlink=$_POST['urunfoto_resimyol'];

this is the variable for path im trying to delete.

Comment: @Barmar can you check codes again pls cuz it seems okey but doesnt remove the images from ftp ? what would it cause that?

Comment: the code looks good, maybe the directory `../../` is not correct.

Comment: actually it is i can see the photos with id on another page with same link "<img style="width: 250px; height: 100px; display: block;" src="../../<?php echo $urunfotocek['urunfoto_resimyol']; ?>" alt="image" />" like this